# How to initialize java db connection when a program after program is deployed

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans

I have created a java program that connects to a jdbc db and performs crud applications. I am done with the coding part but after I deployed it, i am running it and there seems to be no connection to the database since when i run a select query to see all data the table is empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which web server are you using to deploy?

Comment: Java SE or Java EE?

Comment: @BlockX I am using apache.derby server.

Comment: Try connecting to the database that has data, and/or insert data into the database.

Comment: Have you added the driver class as a dependency?

Comment: **Please post the relevant code**: how you get your connection, 
 your inserts, and your selects in an MCVE. How do you get your connection? If there is no exception when you get a connection from your datasource then you probably *do* have a connection. It may be that the table actually is empty, **do you forget to commit your inserts**?

Comment: public DB_Connection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try{
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/tenders; create=true","root"," ");
            if(conn != null){
                System.out.println("Database Connected Succesfully");
                
            }else{
                System.out.println("Unsuccesful Connection");
            }
            
        } catch(SQLException  ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();

Comment: When I run the program through IDE it works fine but after I deploy it, it's like the above class doesn't get a connection till when I restart my IDE and db service.

Comment: @jeromevitolo7 I am not very familiar with apache derby server. But checkout this link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheDerby/article.html

Comment: I used wampserver and thinks worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I used wampserver and thinks worked fine, now i don't need to start netbeans services to get connnection to the db